# React is there a better way to determine if props exist

Tags: reactjs

Is there a better way to determine if a prop has value. I have a shared component that take different props. If I do not use the prop then I get error to get around this issue I been doing the following but would like to know if there is a better way. Basically If I have a delay prop then use the delay

```
const bgStyle = useStyle({
  to: {backgroundColor: 'red', ...props.containerStyle},
  delay: props.delay && props.delay,
 
});
```

Comment: Consider also `useStyle({  to: {backgroundColor: 'red', ...props.containerStyle}, ...props });`

Answer (score 1):

Try using optional chaining:

```js
const bgStyle = useStyle({
  to: {backgroundColor: 'red', ...props.containerStyle},
  delay: props?.delay,
});
```

The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

Learn more about optional chaining from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).